# Input validation method?

Tags: c++

Ok, I am kind of stumped here. I am not sure how to manipulate my code to get the `while loop` to execute. Here is the block of code (i cannot use arrays or vectors per professors instructions). Thanks for any ideas in advance.

```
//function prompts the user for test scores, validates and stores the input scores
void getScore(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3, double &score4, double &score5)
{   
        cout << "Enter a score: ";

    //input validation
    while(score1 < 0 || score1 > 100 || score2 < 0 || score2 > 100 || score3 < 0 || score3 > 100 || score4 < 0 || score4 > 100 || score5 < 0 || score5 > 100)   
    {   
        cout << "Invalid input, all values\n";
        cout << "must be between 0 and 100\n";
        cin >> score1;
            cout << "Enter a score: ";  
        cin >> score2;
            cout << "Enter a score: ";  
        cin >> score3;
        cout << "Enter a score: ";  
        cin >> score4;
            cout << "Enter a score: ";
        cin >> score5;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    }
     if(!(cin >> score >> score2 >> score3 >> score4 >> score5))    
     {
            cout << "You have entered\n"; 
        cout << "non-numeric input.\n";
        cout << "Program is terminated\n";
        cout << "Please try again" << endl;
        exit(0);
     }


}
```

Comment: `i cannot use arrays or vectors per professors instructions` Not even a simple array like `double score[5]`? That seems overly strict.

Comment: @Jesse I wish. I have had this program working per the instructions but there are so many things like this that bug me.

Comment: Here is [an example](http://ideone.com/8v7IR) using arrays, maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you. I would love to use an array, life would be much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not read in the 5 scores without checking and then try to get 5 more scores with checking. I think you need to remove the first five `cin` and `cout`s and just print `Enter 5 scores:`.

Also your condition is wrong,

```
if(!(cin >> score1|| cin >> score2 || cin >> score3 || cin >> score4 || cin >> score5))
```

Should be

```
if(!(cin >> score1 && cin >> score2 && cin >> score3 && cin >> score4 && cin >> score5))
// or, as willhelmtell reminded us, if (!(cin >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> ...))
```

Because you want to check if any of the *fail* (`&&` requires them all to be true), not *succeed* (`||` requires *just one* of them to be true).

Comment: or just `std::cin >> score1 >> score 2 >> ...`

Comment: @SethCarnegie thanks! That worked perfect but now my while loop will not execute. It will exit if the user enters anything other than a digit though.

Comment: @Gmenfan83 the `while` should not execute if the user gives invalid input. When does it not execute (valid or invalid input)?

Comment: @SethCarnegie it doesn't seem to in either situation but the values are still being stored? The first cout outside the loop executes but then there is no more prompt. If I enter an invalid digit the program goes into "dead space" again. But the if statement is executing just fine.

Comment: @Gmenfan83 sorry, please edit your question and post your new code that you are trying now.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the help. I have updated the question and code.

Comment: @Gmenfan83 it seems you removed the code that was reading in the variables. You have to do the `if(!(cin >> score1 && cin >> score2 && cin >> score3 && cin >> score4 && cin >> score5)) { /* error */ }` above the `while` for the variables to actually be read in.

Answer (score 2):

This is not so much an answer as a hint, because this is homework.

**Don't do so much at once.**

If you start by writing

1. A function that reads *one* value
2. A function that validates *one* value

you can compose them into any kind of input & validation logic you want.

That is, given that something like these exist:

```
bool getScore(double& score);  // Returns true if a double was input
bool isValidScore(double score);
```

you could read a given number of values, or read until a non-number is input; that's very easily accomplished using just those two functions you started with.